# Error Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected token '{' css

Tags: css

me remito aqui porque realmente no se cual es el motivo por el cual no me identifica los cambios de css por un error de unexpected token '{'.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset=”utf-8" name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <script src="style.css"></script>
    <title>TITULO</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <a href="#">Portafolio</a>
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
            <div class="animacion start-home"></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Junto con este archivo css

```
nav {
    margin: 27px auto 0;

    position: relative;
    width: 590px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
}

nav a{
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Y me salta error Unexpected token'{' en el primer "nav", entonces no tengo idea, pero me sucede en todos mis codigos que he intentado

Answer (score 1):

Para que enlaces tu `css`, deberías utilizar la etiqueta correspondiente. En tu código, lo que estás haciendo es lo siguiente:

```
<script src="style.css"></script>
```

Por la cual, esta etiqueta es para enlazar archivos `js` (javascript) en tu html (o también, integrar código `js`).

---

La etiqueta que deberías usar para enlazar tus archivos `css` sería la siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no se está linkeando correctamente al **archivo .css**.

Esta línea es la que se debe corregir:

```
<script src="style.css"></script>
```

La siguiente línea estaría bien si se desea hacer referencia a un **archivo .js** (JavaScript) externo.

Ejemplo:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

---

En este caso solo sedebe reemplazar esta línea:

```
<script src="style.css"></script>
```

Por la siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Esto es suficiente para resolver el inconveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, veo claramente que tienes diferentes símbolos en las dobles comillas, trata de escribirlas tu y no copiarlas de otro lado.

```
<meta charset=”utf-8" name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Esta es la que esta mal : ”

Esta debería ser la que esta bien : "

Saludos.